# Top navigation bar not to stick to the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I had my top navigation bar fixed to the top so that it never disappeared when I scrolled down . However, now I want the navigation not to be fixed so that when I scroll down it will disappear and flow with the content. I'm having trouble trying to achieve this.

Can any help me please?

This is the html for the navigation

```
  <header>
        <div class="topBarSymbols">
          <nav class="nav">
            <a href="index.html" id="logoSymbols"> <img src="img/Logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            <a href="sports.html" id="titleSymbols"> <img src="img/footballWhite.png" alt="football"></a>
            <a href="help.html" id="helpSymbols"> <img src="img/helpLogo.png" alt="help icon"></a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
```

The fixed old CSS which worked:

```
.topBar{
 position:fixed;
  z-index: 2;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:12%;
   background-color:#1735E3;
   color:#ffffff;
}

/* styles position of logo */
.nav #logo img {
  position:fixed;
  height: 9%;
  left:5%;
  top:2%;
}
/* styles position of the title of the page represented as an image */
.nav #title img {
  left:140px;
  position:fixed;
  height: 9%;
  top:2%;
  left:42%;
}

/* styles help icon on top right */
.nav #help img {
  left:78%;
  position:fixed;
  height:9%;
  top:2%;
}
```

Current CSS which I'm trying to solve so that nav isn't fixed

```
* styles top blue navigation bar */
.topBarSymbols{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:12%;
  background-color:#1735E3;
  color:#ffffff;
}
/* styles help icon on top right */
.nav #helpSymbols img {
  display: block;
  left:78%;
  height:9%;
  top:2%;
}
/* styles position of logo */
.nav #logoSymbols img {
  display: block;
  height: 9%;
  left:5%;
  top:2%;
}
/* styles position of the title of the page represented as an image */
.nav #titleSymbols img {
  display: block;
  left:140px;
  height: 9%;
  top:2%;
  left:42%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

removing `position: fixed` will allow a natural behavior

Comment: @dippas, it seem author exactly wanted to remove position fixed (or he edited the question). He says: "now I want the navigation NOT to be fixed"...

Answer (score 0):

`.topBar` => `.topBarSymbols` - you got the typo in CSS

also `position:fixed;` has to be done only for the top container, not to all the child elements

---

EDIT: i'm not sure you edited, or it was the original requirement

> now I want the navigation **NOT** to be fixed

In this case you need to remove everywhere `position:fixed`, or to set is to be `relative` or `static`, which is the default.